# Using my After Effects motion graphics in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, frontend, after-effects

I plan to make some motion graphics for my WPF app mainly for screen transitions. Before I jump in to do it, I would like to know if it is possible to export those animations to WPF or I can use only the built in tools to make animations? Or shall I use a sort of image sequence player in WPF for this?